# Parsing Error with MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am currently working on a bit of code to retrieve information from a mysql server through php to be used in an android application using JSON. Unfortunately it appears i am running into errors within my PHP script`

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx"); // edited out details
mysql_select_db("a2275354_gtchose");
$sql=mysql_query("select FName,LName from TEST where UserId=‘".$_REQUEST['userId']."‘");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>`
```

The request for the userId is supplied by a NameValuePairs variable.
the error im recieving is:

> System.out(331): **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in **/home/a2275354/public_html/test.php** on line **4**

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: You **really** need to edit out your db access credentials

Comment: just did that...i'm so stressed out messing with this im forgetting my small details. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: I hope you understood fuzzy and changed them on your server as well. The edit still keeps the details visible.

Comment: Better delete whole question and repost it, it's in reviews history. Or rather change your password.

Comment: Yep, thats the entire script. Upon calling the script i either get that error or this one:  I/System.out(331): <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in <b>/home/a2275354/public_html/test.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are open to SQL injection, it would be wise to learn about escaping your variables in SQL queries `mysql_escape_string()` will probably help you here.

And to the main issue:

Original:

```
"select FName,LName from TEST where UserId=‘".$_RUEST['userId']."‘"
```

Correct:

```
"select FName,LName from TEST where UserId='".$_REQUEST['userId']."'"
```

Notice the differences in the characters enveloping the `".$_REQUEST['userId']."`

It seems you copied the query from an RTF document of sorts so instead of `'` you wrote `‘`

Comment: I thought this, but it'd create a mysql error, not a PHP one. A quick copy and paste into my terminal resulted in no errors.

Comment: That eliminates the main problem, strange considering i hand typed the script. But still gives way to another error. If you could see the comment i left to my question.

Comment: @moneyman232 : this is due to the fact that the query function did not return a correct result object for `mysql_fetch_assoc` to use as a parameter... i'd bet that the problem is still resulting from the `mysql_query` line

Comment: after running the query, and before the `while` loop, debug your SQL by printing the result of `mysql_error()`

Comment: @moneyman232 : the mysql error says it's a syntax issue with the SQL query... can you please echo out the contents of `$sql` before running it?

Comment: I suspect that it's the value in $_REQUEST['userId'] that's the problem as I'm not clear how your are passing your "NameValuePairs", doing `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST['userId'], true).'</pre>';` would be helpful also.

Comment: I've found the problem, I know that table names are not case sensitive in MYSQl, but apparently this is not the case when working with PHP. Thanks for all the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

Yes at a quick glance those single quotes you're using look a bit suspect to me = the ones around the `UserId=‘".$_REQUEST['userId']."‘"` -- they should just be normal single quotes i.e. UserId='".$_REQUEST['userId']."'".

You should also avoid using $_REQUEST -- use $_GET or $_POST instead.